# Maniupating visibility with JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, css, visibility

I have this div

```
<div id="termSheetPopup" style="visibility:hidden;">
```

It's hidden on the page b/c I want it to display in a JQuery popup. I make it a popup with this:

```
function createAndShowTermSheetPopup() {
            $('#termSheetPopup').dialog({
                modal: true,
                resizable: false,
                title: 'Generate Term Sheet',
                width: 350,
                height: 200,
                autoOpen: true,
                buttons: {
                    "Generate": function () {
                        alert('Generating...');
                    },
                    "Cancel": function () {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
```

I want it to make it visible to see in the popup but not on the page when the popup isn't up. How do I do that?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Set `autoOpen` to **false** when you initialize it, then call `$('#termSheetPopup').dialog('open')` when you're ready to use it.

More information can be found [on the jquery-ui demo page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

**Update:** If you can excuse jsFiddle not showing CSS correctly, [this is a demo](http://www.jsfiddle.net/bradchristie/FsyWN/) of what I mean.

Answer (score -1):

http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Dialog#event-create